# Почему .coords() возвращает пустой список?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *


class Tablet:

    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = self.canvas.create_rectangle(170,480, 230,490, fill = color)


tk = Tk()
tk.title('Game')
screen = Canvas(tk, width = 400, height = 500, bd = 0, highlightthickness = 0)
screen.pack()

tablet = Tablet(screen, 'cyan')
print(screen.coords(tablet))
```

При этом, если создавать объект, рисуя его не из моего класса, а просто нарисовать его на холсте, то работает все нормально.

Comment: Разобрался, .coords() - возвращает координаты объекта, нарисованного холстом, мой класс tablet рисует прямоугольник, но им не является, а является им атрибут экземпляра - id.